# Killing of process influences on windows focus

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Our software consists of two programs. One exe is a daemon and the other is a main application. When our main application is running (daemon is also alive of course), daemon window `TopMost` set to `false`, main app starts and kills another process which resides in a tray (which is invisible and disabled in our image of `Windows Embedded`). From one of the windows on deactivating in main app we kill that third-party process and instead of getting back into the previous window, we see the window of the daemon. It happens because of the killing of that third-party app. If we don't kill it, then our main app gets back into the proper window.
How the killing of a third-party process can cause such an odd behavior?

**UPDATE**

Daemon launches main application. Daemon has one window which implements OnActivated as follows:

```
 private void MainWindow_OnActivated(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Topmost = true;
    }

 private void MainWindow_OnDeactivated(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Topmost = false;
    }
```

Killing the third party app on deactivating of one of the main app windows means that in that Window OnDeactivated implemented as follows:

```
protected override void OnDeactivate(bool close) {
   Process.Kill(procId);
}
```

"Why do you expect to "go back to the previous window"?
Well, main app has always one window which is Topmost = true and sometimes we open modal dialogs one on top of another. There is no way for user to manage windows manually such as minimizing them. So I expect to go to the window which we are trying to activate through Caliburn.Micro. But when we ask Caliburn to activate the other window and we kill that app residing in tray then our's Daemon window become activated and Topmost. If we comment out the killing, then we see the window we tried o activate as activated.

By the way, we asked our collegues who developed the third party app to roll out a release without UI. And this does not help. It was just a guess and it failed.

Comment: Do you want us to list all possible ways that can cause a window to show up so you can pick the proper one, or do you think it might be useful to add some relevant details to your question?

Comment: There are no any relevant details in addition to what I said.

Comment: I sincerely beg to differ. How do the mentioned applications interact? What do you mean by deactivating, is that deactivating in the WPF sense (losing focus)? How do you kill the application? Why do you expect to "go back to the previous window"? What is the `TopMost` of the other relevant windows? Why do you hide the daemon window in that manner and not any other manner that does work? But sure, you can refuse to give any additional details so others can help investigate and hope someone else who encountered this specific issue to come by instead, but your chances for that are pretty slim.

Comment: @CodeCaster Updated. Please, ask what you consider you need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well without access to the test environment, my guess is that you don't fully understand when the OnActivated and OnDeactivated events fire.

Terminating a running application that has the focus will cause Windows to pass focus on to another application, maybe the desktop or maybe another application.

Because all you're doing is setting `Topmost` to `false` which does not hide or disable the Window in any way, chances are that Windows is passing focus to your "daemon" which fires the `OnActivated` event which in turns sets `Topmost` to `true`.

I suggest you completely rethink what you're doing.

The "daemon" window should be non-visible when not being displayed, I think this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by starting the third-party process as follows:

```
  var process = new Process {
                    StartInfo = {
                        FileName = fileName, 
                        WorkingDirectory = path, 
                        CreateNoWindow = true, 
                        UseShellExecute = false
                    }
                };
```

The key here is the using of `CreateNoWindow = true` and `UseShellExecute = false`. `UseShellExecute = false` is very important, because otherwise `CreateWindow` property will be ignored. For details, you can look in msdn.

The solution arouse after the answer of @Ashigore, his answer brought the idea of the focus stealing by Windows on launching the third-party app.